# cannot stat folder when moving from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Lots of questions like this one but none of them have helped and i've already killed a day on this *single* command.

Basically I need to understand how I can `mv` a folder into a subfolder in the same directory from a bash script.

To isolate this problem as much as possible i made the following `movetest.sh`:

`sudo mv /home/zoctavous/vault/repos/work/recup_dir1000/ /trash/`

All the folders specified exist and there are no folders that are currently named this. All I get in response is
`mv: cannot stat '/home/zoctavous/vault/repos/work/recup_dir1000/': No such file or directory`

please help :(

Comment: `bash -c 'sudo mv /home/zoctavous/vault/repos/work/recup_dir1000/ /trash/'`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue... I was deleting part of the filename farther up in the script that it was a part of.

`/home/zoctavous/vault/repos/work/recup_dir.1000/` is the *actual* directory name.

the variable for the directory was being stored as shown above
`/home/zoctavous/vault/repos/work/recup_dir1000/`